# Lightweight Simple Video/Audio Editor Linux

Tags: linux, video-editing

I am putting together a montage with a couple of audio tracks and around fifty three minute clips - which will be trimmed to ~5s each. I'm working with 1920x1080 @ 60fps video.

**Ideally**

- Lightweight - Needs to run on my old x201 ThinkPad
- Simple - I don't need fancy effects or transitions
- Has good clip trimming functionality
- Need to be able to "align" or sync the audio and video clips to a high degree of accuracy. I often replay the same few seconds trying to align the beat of the music with the action in the clips.

I'm currently using LosslessCut to trim video clips and Kdenlive to edit and export the final video.

LosslessCut is good but Kdenlive really bogs down my machine and doesn't have fine controls for syncing audio and video.